# Dataframe withcolumn

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe. I am trying to add additional columns.

I keep getting

> AssertionError col should be Column

I have tried casting to string.. then error:

> str object does not have an attribute cast

```
df = df.withColumn("SomeNumber",lit(123)) ## this works
df = df.withColumn("SomeString","why not!") ## this does not work
```

Comment: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-lit-add-literal-constant/ that explains your question best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`withColumn()` expects a column as the second attribute. Thats why you need the `lit()` function which creates a column from your literal.

Comment: What a lit response.